# how to fix module errors in snap7

Tags: python, module, s7-1200, snap7

I'm trying to build a communication between a `plc s7 1200` and an `rpi 3`, I have installed `snap7` but when executing this code I get the following error:

> no module named snap7

This is my code:

```
from time import sleep
import snap7
from snap7.util import *
import struct

plc = snap7.client.Client()
plc.connect("192.168.12.73",0,1)

area = 0x82    # area for Q memory
start = 0      # location we are going to start the read
length = 1     # length in bytes of the read
bit = 0        # which bit in the Q memory byte we are reading

byte = plc.read_area(area,0,start,length)
print "Q0.0:",get_bool(mbyte,0,bit)
plc.disconnect()
```

Comment: Have you installed the module using `pip install`?

Comment: install snap using `python -m pip install python-snap7`